# How to send name value to controller ?(codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to pass the name value on view to controller without submit button?
Thus, the value could be stored in $tabname variable on controller page..

View:

```
<?      
 $i=0;
foreach ($im as $row):
$i++;
 ?>
 <tr>
            <td><? echo $i;?></td>

            <td><? 
            $var ='';
                if(($simn->{"j$i"})==1)
                    $var='done';
                else
                    $var='not yet';
            echo anchor("admin/meeting/status_meeting/".$dk->u_id,"<input type='button' name=".$simn->{"j$i"}." value='".$var."'>"); ?></td>
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
$data['simn'] = $this->mmeeting->get_s_id($id)->row();
```

and

```
function status_meeting($id)
    {
        $tabname= ?
        $ps = array();  
        $person = array('$tabname' => 1     );
        $this->mmeeting->update_status($id,$person,$tabname);
    }
```

Model:

```
private $primary_key= 'k_id';
function get_s_id($id){
        $this->db->where($this->primary_key, $id);
        return $this->db->get("status_meeting");
        }

function update_status($id, $person, $tabname){
        $this->db->where($this->primary_key, $id);
        $this->db->update($tabname, $person);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without submitting you can't get name value in your controller.
So either submit your form  or use ajax to get name value in controller without refreshing the page.